# How to extract a list from pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I'd like to extract and return just the contents, values, of an object in pandas.

I have for example...

```
>>> xx[xx['Business']=="1"]['Label']
3     Sloan School of Management
22                      Business
46       Business Administration
```

I'd like just the list of labels, no index, no panda object, no array.  How can I extract only the data to return a list of the form...

```
["Sloan School of Management", "Business", "Business Administration"]
```

Trying `xx[xx['Business']=="1"]['Label'].values` produced an array:

```
array([Sloan School of Management, Business, Business Administration,
       Professional Development, Business & Management], dtype=object)
```

There must be a built-in and fairly common command for what I'm trying to do, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xx[xx['Business']=="1"]['Label'].tolist()
```

On a related note, I've found IPython's tab completion to be invaluable in my workflow as it helps list all functions of a class. Personally, it was worth the effort to install/configure

Comment: Thanks, and also for the tip.  I was getting bleary-eyed with only dir(object) and didn't see tolist() at all.

Comment: I should probably elaborate. I have it setup to do a fuzzy match, so I would type 'list' to get all '\*list\*'. Helps me a bunch. I don't trust my eyes - bleary or not :)

Comment: @user1827356 - how did you set up fuzzy match. Got a link?

Comment: @John - I have emacs + python-mode + ido-mode with ido-enable-flex-matching turned on. If you aren't an emacs user you could try ipython forums as it does seem like its something it should support outside the box.

Comment: I really, really like using emacs, but am baffled by configuring it for anything beyond simple copy-paste, and have found the emacs support folks kind of, hmm, "cold-shoulder-some," when I try to ask questions ("didn't you read page 1200 of the manual?  It was very clear. Please don't ask simple questions again.")  I myself wasn't able to configure it for python (things like virtualenv, etc. were non-trivial).

Comment: @user1827356 - I'm happy with notebook thanks. I'll wait and see if it ends up in future IPython versions. Otherwise I don't mind a bit of RTFD to understand object methods.